# How to use GZip to create a .zip file

Tags: linux, gzip, compression

Is it possible to use GZip to create a .zip file?  I've been Googling and can't find anything that leads me to believe this is possible

Comment: and not use `zip`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably want to use `zip` and not `gzip`. This should do it:

```
zip -r newzip.zip /path/to/zip/stuff
```

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible. gzip and (pk)zip use different compression formats, and more significantly, zip also packages multiple files, directories, together in one archive.

Comment: They (currently) use the same compression format (deflate), they just package things differently.

Answer (score 5):

The original zip format is the same as:

```
 tar -cZf package.zip files....
```

(note the capital Z uses the compress lib - using the small 'z' would give a gzipped archive which pk/winzip can't understand).

i.e. no, you can't use gzip to create a pkzip file - but I'd be surprised to find a Unix machine which had gzip but not compress.

Comment: No it isn't. Zip files are more than just a tarball passed through compress.

Comment: Similar to != same as.  Tar stores unis permissions and such that zip does not.  Zip also compresses only 32kb at a time so that you can extract a single file without having to decompress everything that came before it; tar compresses the whole thing at once ( giving better compression ).  Most importantly, they are different file formats that are not recognized by the other tool.